# Qbasic - trying to call a sub, but i get a message that says "Expected CALL, subname, (...)"

Tags: arrays, subroutine, qbasic

Here is the code, it takes 5 names and alphabetizes them. I have a sub that sorts the names but apparently i'm not calling it in the correct way.

```
DIM i AS INTEGER
DIM q AS INTEGER
DIM a AS STRING
DIM n(5) AS STRING
DIM z AS INTEGER
DIM x AS INTEGER
DIM y AS INTEGER
DIM g AS INTEGER

start:
CLS

FOR i = 1 TO 5
    INPUT "Name:", n(i) 'receiving 5 names
NEXT i

call Sort()                                **This is the line with the error**

PRINT "Names in Alphabetical Order:"
FOR i = 1 TO 5
    PRINT n(i)
NEXT i
INPUT "Again(y, n)", a
IF LCASE$(a) = "y" THEN GOTO start
IF LCASE$(a) <> "y" THEN STOP

'end of main program

SUB Sort (`enter code here`)
    FOR i = 1 TO 5
        FOR q = 1 TO 4
        IF LCASE$(n(q)) > LCASE$(n(q + 1)) THEN SWAP n(q), n(q + 1)
        IF LCASE$(n(q)) = LCASE$(n(q + 1)) THEN

            z = LEN(n(q))
            x = LEN(n(q + 1))
            IF z > x THEN g = x
            IF z < x THEN g = z

            IF z > 1 AND x > 1 THEN
                FOR y = 2 TO g
                    IF LCASE$(MID$(n(q), y, 1)) > LCASE$(MID$(n(q + 1), y, 1)) THEN
                        SWAP n(q), n(q + 1)
                        END
                    END IF
                    IF y = g THEN SWAP n(q), n(q + 1)
                NEXT y
            END IF
        END IF
    NEXT q
NEXT i

END SUB
```

I have tried putting a parameter in the sub, "SUB Sort(n())", the array that has the names in it, but it said incorrect array type.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the fact that you typed `SORT()` when there are no arguments.

Invoking a `SUB` or `FUNCTION` with correct syntax can be a bit strange in QB at first, and the syntax for the `CALL` keyword makes things even more confusing:

```
' No arguments means you MUST NOT include the () afterward.
CALL SubNameE

' One non-array argument: n
CALL SubNameX(n)

' Two non-array arguments: a, b
CALL SubNameY(a, b)

' An array argument and a non-array argument: arr(), v
CALL SubNameZ(arr(), v)
```

Notice how arrays are passed to `SUB` and `FUNCTION` procedures using `name()`.  The interpreter probably gets confused when you write `call SORT()` as `SORT()` is the syntax for an array, not a `SUB`/`FUNCTION` call with no arguments.

You can also write the above lines of code without the `CALL` keyword if that helps you:

```
' No arguments means only the procedure name is listed.
SubNameE

' One non-array argument: n
SubNameX n

' Two non-array arguments: a, b
SubNameY a, b

' An array argument and a non-array argument: arr(), v
SubNameZ arr(), v
```

Note that for a `SUB` or `FUNCTION` to accept an array argument, it must have them declared, like this:

```
SUB SORT (n() AS STRING)
' or if you wanted to use a type suffix
SUB SORT (n$())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to pass an array to a sort subroutine in qb64:

```
DIM n(5) AS STRING
n(1) = "zachary smith"
n(2) = "xerox johnson"
n(3) = "yackle jones"
n(4) = "arnold aglet"
n(5) = "beth anderson"
CALL Sort(n())
FOR i = 1 TO 5: PRINT n(i): NEXT
END
SUB Sort (n() AS STRING)
FOR i = 1 TO 5
    FOR j = i + 1 TO 5
        IF n(i) > n(j) THEN SWAP n(i), n(j)
    NEXT
NEXT
END SUB
```

Here is an easier way to call a sort subroutine without specifying a parameter:

```
DIM SHARED n(5) AS STRING
n(1) = "zachary smith"
n(2) = "xerox johnson"
n(3) = "yackle jones"
n(4) = "arnold aglet"
n(5) = "beth anderson"
CALL Sort
FOR i = 1 TO 5: PRINT n(i): NEXT
END
SUB Sort
FOR i = 1 TO 5
    FOR j = i + 1 TO 5
        IF n(i) > n(j) THEN SWAP n(i), n(j)
    NEXT
NEXT
END SUB
```